# 'Shape' legend only created for first plot of a group

Tags: altair

I have a plot of 6 charts which are generated by loop in an identical fashion (only the sites plotted changes).  The plots are then joined:

chart= plot_group_0 & plot_group_1 ... etc.

[image]

However the secondary legend detail designating the ‘Interval’ at the top right only appears for the first plot.

This ‘Interval’ legend is automatically generated by the ‘shape’ feature.

shape=alt.Shape('interval:N',title='Interval'),

Is there a way to explicitly force it to appear for each plot?  The relevant 'shape' line is obviously executed for each plot in the loop so I'm not sure why it only appears once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenated charts share their legends and scales by default. If you want legends or scales to be independent, you can set the `resolve` property, as discussed in [Scale and Guide Resolution](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/scale_resolve.html)

To share the scale but use independent legends, use:

```
chart = plot_group_0 & plot_group_1 #... etc
chart = chart.resolve_legend(shape='independent')
```

To have independent scales as well as independent legends, use

```
chart = chart.resolve_scale(shape='independent')
```